# No Convert (to Cloud Service) Menu Item for My Web Application in Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, azure, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

There's no Convert menu option for my MVC web application in Visual Studio 2015 when I right-click on my web application. The Azure templates are already there in Visual Studio as seen below, so I guess the Azure SDK is already installed in Visual Studio. Why can't I convert my web app to cloud service?

[image]

[image]

I have Microsoft Azure App Service Tools v.2.9.1 - Visual Studio 2015 installed.

[image]

Comment: I'm using VS2015 Community Edition and I can see the "Convert" menu. Can you please tell what version of Azure SDK is installed on your machine? I have 2.9.5.1.

Comment: I have Microsoft Azure App Service Tools v.2.9.1 - Visual Studio 2015 installed. Where can I get the update?

Comment: You can download old versions of SDK from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/downloads/archive-net-downloads/.

Comment: I have installed Visual Studio Community 2017 and still cannot see Convert menu item. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I have checked this issue on my side. The Target framework of my MVC applications target over .NET Framework 4.6+, and I found I also could not see the `Convert` menu as follows:

[image]

Then, I searched the web and found a similar [issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f570225b-7039-415a-91f1-106afa14a1c3/azure-cloud-service-cannot-convert-an-aspnet-mvc-application-to-an-azure-cloud-service-in-vs-2015?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview). Based my test, I found if I downgrade the .NET Framework lower than 4.6, then I could see the The **Convert, Convert to Azure Cloud Service Project** command and I could convert my web application to cloudservice and deplopy to azure successfully.

[image]

In summary, you could try to check whether it could help you. Also, you could refer to this official document about [How to migrate and publish a web application to azure Cloud Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-migrate-publish-web-app-to-cloud-service#enable-a-web-application-for-deployment-to-azure).

Comment: Yes, that was it. Thank you very much!